# datagrid filter for relation object as text field (insted of dropdown) in sonata admin in symfony 2.4

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.4

I have entity 'Action' with relation to 'User'. Created Admin CRUD controller in SonataAdminBundle. Everything works fine except user filter is rendered as dropdown list. I have 8k user count and growing so you must see why this is a problem.
**I want user filter to be text input and on submit to search with `LIKE %username%`**

Right now I add user filter like this - `$datagridMapper->add('user')`.

I know I can add filter type and field type but I am not able to find the right combination and options. Found information on http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html but still no success.

### Final solution

Following Alex Togo answer I used this code:

```
$datagridMapper->add('user', 'doctrine_orm_callback', array(
'callback' => function($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
    if (empty($value['value'])) {
        return;
    }
    $queryBuilder->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.user', $alias), 'u');
    $queryBuilder->where('u.username LIKE :username');
    $queryBuilder->setParameter('username', '%'.$value['value'].'%');
    return true;
},
'field_type' => 'text'
))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed something like this on a project. I implemented this feature using [this](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html#callback). You can try to set the 'field_type' option to 'text' (I used 'choice' in the project I worked at) and add the querybuilder actions you need to filter.

Answer (score 4):

Use **doctrine_orm_choice** option.

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper->add(
            'module',
            'doctrine_orm_choice',
            [],
            'choice',
            [
                'choices' => $this->filterModuleList
            ]
        )

        ....
```

Comment: How would filterModuleList() look like? Because it seems using this method I would get default dropdown menu with thousands of values.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but is a helpful reference if someone's looking into doing the opposite (dropdown for a text or int field)