# How to add a custom callback method in configureListFields() sonata admin?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I want to add a custom callback method on a sonata field list `configureListFields()`

It's possible in the configureDatagridFilters() method like below:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $filter)
{
    $filter
        ->add('user', 'doctrine_orm_callback', array(
            'callback'   => array($this, 'customMethod'),
        ));
}
```

But is it possible in the configureListFields() method ?

Comment: What do you need the callback for? There may be other ways of doing what you are trying to achieve. I don't think the ListMapper supports a callback.

Comment: The main column is user, and the other column is bookings. I want to filter the user's bookings by a certain status, and count them

Answer (score -1):

Your attempt using the *doctrine_orm_callback* is correct:
[Doctrine2 ORM Admin's documentation - Reference - Filter Field Definition  (2.2) - 5.5.3. Callback](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/2-2/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html#callback)

Use the provided example and replace **comments** with your **bookings** and then apply your conditions to the **builder**:

```
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('title')
        ->add('enabled')
        ->add('tags', null, array(), null, array('expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true))
        ->add('author')
        ->add('with_open_comments', 'doctrine_orm_callback', array(
            'callback' => function($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
                if (!$value) {
                    return;
                }

                $queryBuilder->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.comments', $alias), 'c');
                $queryBuilder->andWhere('c.status = :status');
                $queryBuilder->setParameter('status', Comment::STATUS_MODERATE);

                return true;
            },
            'field_type' => 'checkbox'
        ))
    ;
}
```

Comment: Similar to this maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932156/datagrid-filter-for-relation-object-as-text-field-insted-of-dropdown-in-sonata